# $A^2 = AB, |(A-B)|$ and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A, B$ be square matrices. $A \ne 0$ (as a matrix) and $A^2 = AB$. How can I prove that $ |(A-B)| = 0$? I think that key is a chain $|(A-B)|=\dots = |(B-A)|$ but not sure if it's the right way. And prove that $0$ is $A$-eigenvalue.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your chain is trying to do. Note $A-B = -(B-A)$

Comment: Try working with $(A+B)(A-B)$.

Comment: You know that $A(A-B)=0$, and because $A\ne 0$ there is at least one nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av\ne 0$. Now if $\det(A-B)\ne 0$, then ...

Comment: Pretty sure you need $A\neq B$ to get $0$ is a an $A$-eigenvalue.  Otherwise you can put any nonzero matrix with any eigenvalues you want in for $A=B$ and meet the criterea.. As soon as you have $A\neq B$, the you can then determine if $A$ is invertible or not, and having a 0 eigenvalue is equivalent to not being invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^2=AB \\
AA-AB=0 \\
A(A-B)=0 \\
A \neq0 \\
\text{therefore,} \\ A-B=0\\ \text{Now for eigenvalues. }\\
\text{Let }Av=\lambda v \\
A^2 v = A\lambda v = \lambda^2v\\
\text{But we also have}\\
(A^2)v=0v=0,\text{Since $A^2$ is 0. Now we have 2 equations.}
A^2v=\lambda^2v=0\\
\text{Therefore $\lambda $ must be 0. Hope this helps} 
$

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's helps.

Comment: $A(A-B)=0$. It means that:$\det(A*(A-B))=0$, $\det(A)*\det(A-B)=0$